# Golang: чтение файла с определенной строки/позиции

Tags: golang

*Стоит задача:* читать постоянно обновляемый файл с данными.
Файл вырастает до более 100000 строк и необходимо прочитать его со 100001 до конца файла.

Какой алгоритм / пакет / метод можно было бы использовать для реализации?

Comment: Строки в вашем файле с данными стандартной длины? Если да то можете пропустить `f.Seek(100000 * strLen, 0)` перед тем как читать. В `strLen` нужно учитывать перевод строки CRLF. Далее как просто читаете как в ответе от Ainar-G.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте [буферизованный сканер](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner). Пример, печатающий все строки после 100 000:

```golang
f, err := os.Open("test.txt")
// Check err.
s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
n := 0
for s.Scan() {
    n++
    if n > 100000 {
        _, err = os.Stdout.WriteString(s.Text() + "\n")
        // Check err.
    }
}
err = s.Err()
// Check err.
```

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз вопрос. Пока вы прочитаете 1 млн строк (каждая из которых может быть по гигабайту) -- можно уйти на пенсию.